# Как переопределить подписку на PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Есть класс, который реализует INotifyPropertyChanged, следовательно, в классе есть событие

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
```

На это событие происходит подписка в более чем 300 местах простым оператором +=. Есть цель перейти на использование WeakEventManager для избежания утечек памяти. Конечно, совсем не хочется изменять способ подписки аж в 300 местах, поэтом хочется как-то выкрутиться.
Все что я смог придумать (но это не работает):

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            WeakEventManager<BaseNotifyPropertyChanged, EventArgs>.AddHandler(this, "PropertyChanged", (EventHandler<EventArgs>)value);
            //либо же
            PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(this, value, "IsDirty");
        }
        remove
        {
           //аналогичный код
        }
    }
```

И в случае с WeakEventManager, и с PropertyChangedEventManager компилятор ругается на невозможность приведения PropertyChangedEventHandler к EventHandler. Можно ли как-то решить проблему?

UPD:

Проблемы выше я решил вот таким способом:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            WeakEventManager<BaseNotifyPropertyChanged, EventArgs>.AddHandler(this, "PropertyChanged", (sender, e) => value(sender, (PropertyChangedEventArgs)e));
        }
        remove
        {
            WeakEventManager<BaseNotifyPropertyChanged, EventArgs>.RemoveHandler(this, "PropertyChanged", (sender, e) => value(sender, (PropertyChangedEventArgs)e));
        }
    }
```

Но теперь вот в таком коде

```
    protected virtual void RaiseOnPropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
    }
```

Компилятор ругается:
*The event PropertyChanged can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=*

Текст ошибки довольно рапространенный, но вот появляется у других людей в другом контексте.

Comment: Ну, «невозможность приведения PropertyChangedEventHandler к EventHandler» как раз понятна, а зачем вы делаете cast силой? Почему не использовать правильный тип?

Comment: Вы правы, я обновил вопрос.

Comment: Окей, я смог [заставить код _откомпилироваться_](http://pastebin.com/cmLyPhcg). Но я не уверен в его _правильности_, нужно поэксперименторовать и почитать документацию.

Comment: Он компилится, но упадет в рантайме, т.к. WeakEventManager не увидит private событие PropertyChangedInternal

Comment: Ну, это событие можно сделать публичным на время, чтобы посмотреть, решает ли это проблему.

Answer (score 2):

В классе Source есть событие Notify, к нему можно подключить обработчик как обычно. Но при этом в реализации Notify используются слабые ссылки на подписчиков. Если на Target нет каких-либо других ссылок, то и в Source не остается ссылка на Target.

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

static void Main(string[] args) {
    var s = Start();
    s.Run();      // будет вызван t.Handler
    var arr = new int[100000000];
    Console.WriteLine("APP: arr[{0}]", arr.Length);
    s.Run();       // t.Handler больше не вызывается
    Console.WriteLine("APP: done");
}

static Source Start() {
    var s = new Source();
    var t = new Target();
    s.Notify += t.Handler;
    return s;
}

class Target {
    int[] arr = new int[10000000];
    public void Handler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("TARGET: notified");
    }
}

class Source {
    List<WeakReference<EventHandler>> _Handlers;
    public Source() {
        _Handlers = new List<WeakReference<EventHandler>>();
    }
    public event EventHandler Notify
    {
        add { _Handlers.Add(new WeakReference<EventHandler>(value)); }
        remove { Console.WriteLine("SOURCE: remove"); /* todo */ }
    }
    public void Run() {
        foreach (var w in _Handlers) {
            EventHandler h;
            if (w.TryGetTarget(out h))
                h.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

При необходимости надо периодически очищать _Handlers от WeakReference c 'битыми' ссылками.