# Присваивание события делегату

Tags: c#

На просторах интернета нашел такой вот код:

```
using System;

class a
{
    public event EventHandler Ev;
    public void EventStart()
    {
        EventHandler temp = Ev;
        if (temp != null)
            temp(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
class demo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        a A = new a();
        A.Ev += (o, e) => { Console.WriteLine(1); };
        A.Ev += (o, e) => { Console.WriteLine(2); };
        A.Ev += (o, e) => { Console.WriteLine(3); };
        A.EventStart();
    }
}
```

И меня очень удивила эта строчка `EventHandler temp = Ev;` почему присваивание происходит нормально ? Ведь событие и делегат это разные вещи. Событие это поле с аксессорами `add` `remove`, которые добавляют/удаляют методы (делегаты) в "делегатный" массив. То есть если грубо то это присваивание что-то вроде `Action a = new Action[n]`. Особенно удивило, что если на это событие сделать много подписок, то почему-то по вызову одного делегата, они все запускаются. Растолкуйте пожалуйста.

Comment: чтобы не вызывать `if (temp != null)` можно Ev определить так: `public event EventHandler Ev = delegate {};`

Comment: @Stack присваивание локальной переменной и проверка переменной делается не для этого.

Comment: @andreycha _"не для этого"_ -- проверка делает для того, чтобы не было проблем когда есть разные потоки. и `var tmp = .... if(tmp ...)` -  недостаточно. поэтому проще всего определить как `= delegate {};`

Comment: @Stack да. Просто вы так написали, как будто проверка вставлена только оттого, что поле по умолчанию имеет значение null. А уж если присваивать значение по умолчанию, то не худо бы и `readonly` еще поставить. *"и var tmp = .... if(tmp ...) - недостаточно"* -- почему же?

Comment: @andreycha _"почему же?"_ -- из многопоточности. надо ставить lock см. [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2205726/5673266)

Comment: @Stack я думаю, что с локом перед вызовом события Скит переборщил. Присваивание является атомарной операцией, а локальные переменные -- они per thread.

Comment: @andreycha _"с локом перед вызовом события Скит переборщил"_ -- lock нужен для 'защиты' от JIT. который может заменить `EventHandler temp = Ev; if (temp != null)' на `if(Ev != null)` -- см. [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883956.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дело в том, что все делегаты являются потомками [`MulticastDelegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.multicastdelegate(v=vs.110).aspx). Т.е. каждый делегат -- это уже, как вы выразились, "делегатный массив", контейнер, который содержит список вызовов.

Далее, событие -- это просто член класса, имеющий тип делегата (`EventHandler` в данном случае) плюс некоторый синтаксис, позволяющий реализовать механизм подписки/отписки (те самые `add`/`remove`). Учитывая это две вещи, присваивание является абсолютно корректным действием (и делается для того, чтобы предотвратить `NullReferenceException` в многопоточной среде).

По поводу вызова всех подписок. Как я уже сказал, каждый делегат содержит в себе список всех вызовов. А потому при срабатывании события вызываются все подписки. Подписки вызываются синхронно, при это порядок их вызова не определен*.

Рекомендую почитать книгу Джеффри Рихтера "CLR via C#", глава 11, а также книгу Джона Скита "C# для профессионалов", глава 2 ([есть перевод на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/198694/)).

---

*строго говоря, `MulticastDelegate` действительно вызывает подписки в порядке их добавления. Поэтому для field-like событий можно говорить об определенном порядке вызова. Однако этот факт является деталью реализации и полагаться на него не нужно. В случае же событий, имеющих аксессоры `add`/`remove`, полагаться на порядок нельзя вообще, поскольку в общем случае неизвестно, каким образом внутри происходит подписка.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь !

Comment: @PolyakovSergey не за что!

Comment: _"Подписки вызываются синхронно, при это порядок их вызова не определен"_ -- а разве вызываются не в порядке их добавления? один поток идет по списку и вызывает обработчки. или не так?

Comment: вызывать подписчиков можно самому. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467419/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-propertychanged/476270#476270)

Comment: @Stack обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к правильному ответу @andreycha:

Дело в том, что для событий, определённых без явного указания `add`/`remove`, внутренний делегат, в котором хранится список подписчиков, доступен по тому же имени, что и событие, **изнутри** класса. Снаружи доступно, разумеется, только событие, иначе это было бы нарушением инкапсуляции.

Дополнительное чтение по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/226698/10105

Comment: Да, но насколько мне известно, хотя могу и ошибаться, то этот внутренний делегат не простой, а массив. То есть в контексте моего примера EventHandler [] Ev = new [] EventHandler. То есть я это вижу как EventHandler Ev = new [] EventHandler что недопустимо.

Comment: @PolyakovSergey _"насколько мне известно, хотя могу и ошибаться"_ -- посмотрите исходник метода [GetInvocationList()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/multicastdelegate.cs,461) в нем создается массив

Comment: @PolyakovSergey: Это `MulticatDelegate`, если я правильно помню. У него внутри их целый список.